# apache vhost config so that _default_ goes to another IP

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, port-forwarding, virtualhost

hi I have 3 apache servers but one inbound ip with one port 80 to listen on. all port 80 traffice goes to 192.168.1.10. But I want to vhost to send certaindomains like `www.mydomain.co.uk` to the local folders required, and certain domains to offserver to server2 (192.168..1.11) and this works for domains `wiki.mydomain.co.uk` it works perfectly but what I ALSO want to do is send all the "spare" unknown traffic to 192.168.1.12 and this ISN'T working as I would hope.

All I want to do is send traffic that isn't listed to the server 192.168.1.12. When I do a port check on the machine 192.168.1.12 nothing is arriving.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

Alias /errors/ /var/www/html/mydomain/errors/

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mydomain.co.uk
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain/www
  ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404error.php
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName admin.mydomain.co.uk
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain/admin
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName wiki.mydomain.co.uk
  ServerAdmin root@localhost
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.11/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.11/
  <Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/wiki.mydomain.co.uk.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/wiki.mydomain.co.uk.err.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.12/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.12/
</VirtualHost>
```

apachectl -S

VirtualHost

```
 configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          www.mydomain.co.uk (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.mydomain.co.uk (/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf:5)
         port 80 namevhost www.mydomain.co.uk (/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf:5)
         port 80 namevhost www.mydomain.co.uk (/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf:12)
         port 80 namevhost admin.mydomain.co.uk (/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf:18)
         port 80 namevhost wiki.mydomain.co.uk (/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf:23)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the default vhost **first** in the configuration file.

The first vhost will be used if no match against the Host: sent is found.  In your case that means this should be top:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.12/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.12/
</VirtualHost>
```

(I've dropped the "_default_"  because it is redundant.)

Comment: thanks Steve, when I do this everything gets redirected and all the vhosts fail :-/

Comment: @user26676 Provide the output from `apachectl -S`?

Comment: yes, I ran it for you, see edit

Comment: hmm it appears it's only the `www` that is failing: (the others `admin` and `wiki` work) so it appears my `www` is wrongly set up (and hitherto been working incorrectly as a default (so still "working")) but I don't see how it's different.

Comment: the issue was the ServerName was `www.mydomain.co.uk.` in `httpd.conf` - renamed the ServerName and it's fine

Comment: Damn timezones, sorry I wasn't around earlier.  Glad you got there in the end though!